# VBScript regex not working to grab status code

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am getting a no match with the below VBScript.  Is something off in my code?

**Test**

```
Error Type: SMTP[nl] Remote server (166.216.149.129) issued an error.[nl] hMailServer sent: RCPT TO:<8583390609@txt.att.net>[nl] Remote server replied: 550 5.1.1 <8583390609@txt.att.net> recipient does not exist here.[nl]
```

**Pattern**

```
^.*Remote server replied: ([0-9]{3}).*$
```

**Logging**

```
3544    "2019-05-06 23:09:51.609"   "Running" 
3544    "2019-05-06 23:09:51.609"   "Error Type: SMTP[nl] Remote server (166.216.149.129) issued an error.[nl] hMailServer sent: RCPT TO:<8583390609@txt.att.net>[nl] Remote server replied: 550 5.1.1 <8583390609@txt.att.net> recipient does not exist here.[nl]" 
3544    "2019-05-06 23:09:51.609"   "No Match"
```

**VBScript**

```
Dim regex, matches, match, strResult

    EventLog.Write("Running")
    EventLog.Write(sErrorMessage)

    Set regex = New RegExp
    regex.IgnoreCase = True
    regex.Pattern = "^.*Remote server replied: ([0-9]{3}).*$"

    Set matches = regex.Execute(sErrorMessage)

    If matches.Count >= 1 Then
            Set match = matches(0)
            If match.SubMatches.Count >= 1 Then
                strResult = match.SubMatches(0)
            EventLog.Write(strResult)
            Else
EventLog.Write("NO SUBMATCHES")
                strResult = ""
                exit sub
            End If
    Else
EventLog.Write("No Match")
            strResult = ""
            exit sub
    End If
```

Comment: Off topic, what in the world does that even mean when I am talking about regex and VBScript?  Showing future users it could be a multi line issue will not help future users, you have to be kidding me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
regex.MultiLine = True
```

The [nl] is a new line carrier and I guess I need to tell the regex that.